# Where is Junit's Tools-> create unit test in NB 7.3.1

Tags: java, junit, netbeans-7

I have recently installed NB 7.3.1, and installed the JUnit plugin. In the old days, JUnit was bundled with NetBeans. I used it all that time.

I want to use it now, but I can't find any command, button, tool, etc to cause Netbeans to create the shell unit tests for me.

What am I doing wrong? How do I find it?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a test folder. Go to your project properties, and under Sources, in Test Package Folders, make sure you have at least one folder where you want to put your test sources.

If the button is still greyed out after that, you can go to File > New File > Unit Tests > JUnit Test. If it gives you an error message, it may help you solve the problem.